# It is possible to detect geofence events without requestLocationUpdates?

Tags: android, android-geofence

It is possible make the geofence exit and enter events trigger without any location request?
Even when there is no other application requesting location, only with the device GPS turned on?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. The device can know its location from the nearby wifis and the phone signal.

The location accuracy of these methods is not as good as with a gps signal stablished but if the radius is big enough as 150m or more as it's recommended in the [geofencing docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#choose-the-optimal-radius-for-your-geofence) this is enough. And bigger in rural areas:

> Choose the optimal radius for your geofence
> For best results, the minimum radius of the geofence should be set between 100 - 150 meters. When Wi-Fi is available location accuracy is usually between 20 - 50 meters. When indoor location is available, the accuracy range can be as small as 5 meters. Unless you know indoor location is available inside the geofence, assume that Wi-Fi location accuracy is about 50 meters.
>
> When Wi-Fi location isn't available (for example, when you are driving in rural areas) the location accuracy degrades. The accuracy range can be as large as several hundred meters to several kilometers. In cases like this, you should create geofences using a larger radius.

Comment: But even if i am not doing the requestUpdatesLocation? My question is, is geofence  autonomous doing its work?

Comment: Yes, the only difference is the accuracy and that location updates will not be so frequent as with the gps turned on by requesting location updates